# VMware tools easy install relic

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, vmware

I made a fresh 'easy install' of 12.04 on vmware workstation.

This is yet another problem (quite a few have been asked here.) with the vmware tools installation. I managed to install vmware tools manually. But I still end up at the terminal with a message - [image: Terminal Login Screen]

I have managed to change the default runlevel to 5 and have made sure that X11 common and lightdm are started at runlevel 5 (Used sysv-rc-conf & checkconfig). When I login, I am at runlevel 5, but `lightdm` or X server are not in the `ps aux` list.

What am I missing? how do I get rid of this message and start the graphical login manager?

PS: I installed a GB of other apps by logging in and really wanted to salvage it over reinstalling.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong here but i'd throw the VM into trash and do a fresh install without easy install. Just select other linux and configure it yourself - it's just like setting up Ubuntu on a real hardware.

Comment: I would have preferred that, but I logged in and installed a GB of other apps - xfce, build essentials, updates, kernel headers, eclipse etc. I would prefer to salvage this to redoing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo -s
mv /etc/issue.backup /etc/issue
mv /etc/rc.local.backup /etc/rc.local
mv /opt/vmware-tools-installer/lightdm.conf /etc/init
reboot
```

This will restore these files from the backup that VMWare made durin VMWare tools installation.

Comment: Not a solution that I liked or used, but I have a poor acceptance ratio and had to choose one. The other answer here is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use custom installation in vmware and don't install it through easy install.try that